# AJAX requests and CookieOverflow in RoR

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, session-cookies

I'm making a dynamic checklist and I'm having some problems with AJAX requests and database updating.  Basically when an item is clicked, I asynchronously update the database to say that an item has been clicked.  Here is the javascript :

```
    $('.checkBoxContainer').click( function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#FFF3D8");
    $(this).find("input").attr("disabled", "disabled")
    $(this).find("p").css("text-decoration", "line-through")
                     .css("color", "#AAA");
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "updateDone",
        data : "id=" + $(this).attr("id") 
    });
});
```

Here is the method in the controller

```
def updateDone
    currentItem = Item.find(params[:id])
    currentItem.update_attribute(:done => true)
  end
```

The following code works for only 5 items or so before the command prompt shoots me a "Cookie Overflow" error.  I'm not using any cookie or session data so how is this producing this error?  If it turns out to be a cookie problem (though I don't see how) how would I clear the session/cookie data in the server/browser so the client can make more than 5 items on the checklist?

Comment: can you take a screenshot or copy/paste the error messagE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either store less stuff in the session, or move the session store to [memcache](https://github.com/mperham/dalli).
The default [cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) based session store can only hold upto ~ 4kb of data, because cookies as per standard are not allowed to have a bigger size.

Comment: If you get "Cookie Overflow" surely somewhere in your app something puts data in the session until overflow.